# Adding Some "Spacers" to a Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6yU6N/

Here's a mockup of what I want to accomplish:

[image]

As you can see, I want to add a tiny space between the header and the first "pick container."  And to add a space between each pick container.

What's the best what to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this where you need some space:

```
....
<tr class="big_gap">
  <td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
...
<tr class="small_gap">
  <td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
....

<style>
  .big_gap td {
    height: 19px;
  }

  .small_gap td {
    height: 10px;
  }

</style>
```

This way you can give the specific appearance to the gap in between.
And if it doesnt behave well you can add a   in the `<td colpan="4">&nbsp;</td>`